# jquery drill down version 2

Tags: jquery

Given the following HTML output from my aspx page, which displays a checkboxlist;

```
 <div id="selectContainer" class="wrapper" >

    <div id="cbxArea" class="checkbox">

       <table id="ChartstoDisplay" style="border-color:DimGray;border-width:2px;border-style:Solid;width:300px;">

<tr>

    <td><input id="ChartstoDisplay_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$ChartstoDisplay$ChartstoDisplay_0" value="Selected Year Cumulative P/L" /><label for="ChartstoDisplay_0">Selected Year Cumulative P/L</label></td>

</tr><tr>

    <td><input id="ChartstoDisplay_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$ChartstoDisplay$ChartstoDisplay_1" value="Month by Month P/L for selected year" /><label for="ChartstoDisplay_1">Month by Month P/L for selected year</label></td>

</tr><tr>

    <td><input id="ChartstoDisplay_2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$ChartstoDisplay$ChartstoDisplay_2" value="All Commodities P/L for selected year" /><label for="ChartstoDisplay_2">All Commodities P/L for selected year</label></td>

</tr><tr>

    <td><input id="ChartstoDisplay_3" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$ChartstoDisplay$ChartstoDisplay_3" value="Current Month&#39;s P/L by Commodity" /><label for="ChartstoDisplay_3">Current Month's P/L by Commodity</label></td>

</tr><tr>
</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to change the class of the individual item when it is selected. I am having trouble getting my jquery to find the right object to change the class of. Here is my latest iteration.

```
 $('#ChartstoDisplay').change(
          function () {
              $('#ChartstoDisplay').each(function () {
                 $(this).is(':checked').$('label').toggleclass("selected");
              });
          });
```

I also tried this way

```
 $('#ChartstoDisplay').change(
          function () {
              $('#ChartstoDisplay').each(function () {
                 $(this).is(':checked').$('label').attr.add('style',"color:darkgreen;");
              });
          });
```

Here is the completed script working in it's entirety

```
 //this script will change the style of the "Select All" checkbox and make visible the "Build Chart" button
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#ChartstoDisplayAll').change(
          function () {
              if ($('#ChartstoDisplayAll').is(':checked')) {
                  $(this).next().addClass("selected");
                  $('#buttons').addClass("buttonsshow").removeClass('buttonshide');
                  $("#cbxArea input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
                      $(this).prop("checked", true);
                      $(this).siblings("label").toggleClass("selected");
                  });
              } else {
                  $('#buttons').addClass("buttonshide").removeClass('buttonsshow');
                  $(this).next().removeClass("selected");
                  $("#cbxArea input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
                      $(this).prop("checked", false);
                      $(this).siblings("label").removeClass("selected");
                  });
              }
          });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$("#cbxArea input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
   $(this).siblings("label").toggleClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: Well i cant put it here because its too long...the .is(":checked") line im assuming is NOT checking the checkboxes in the checkboxlist.... $("#cbxArea input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
                          $(this).is(":checked");
                          $(this).siblings("label").toggleClass("selected");
                      });

Comment: well change your code to this --

$("#cbxArea input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () { $(this).siblings("label").toggleClass("selected"); });

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[id^="ChartstoDisplay_"]').on('change', function() {
  $(this).next('label')[$(this).prop('checked')?'addClass':'removeClass']("selected");
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PugWc/1/)

To iterate over all of them, do:

```
$('[id^="ChartstoDisplay_"]').on('change', function () {
    $('[id^="ChartstoDisplay_"]').each(function(i,e) {
        $(this).next('label')[$(this).prop('checked')?'addClass':'removeClass']("selected");
    });
});​
```

Comment: That is not working. This works, it does change the text color for each selected item in the list. This is used when a separate select all check box is checked. I cannot get the checkboxlist (with 5 items in it) to change the text color individually.....$('#ChartstoDisplay').each(function () {
                         $('label').toggleClass("selected");
                     });

Comment: adeneo, thank you i see it works great in the fiddle but it doesnt work on my actual page.

Comment: You are iterating over one single ID, ID's are unique, and there is no each for `#ChartstoDisplay`, it's just a table element. Try explaining better, do you have to check all the boxes every time, or do you just want a button to check them all ??? Why it's not working on your page is very hard to diagnose for someone else, you will have to look in the console (F12) for errors etc.

Comment: There is a checkbox whose id is ChartstoDisplayAll, when that checkbox is selected it should do three things, 1. Show a button that is defaulted to invisible, 2. change its text color to bold green via the .selected class and 3. check all the checkboxes in the checkboxlist below it (5 items) and make their text bold green as well. I have the first two working, item 3 i cannot figure out... Here is the script to accomplish items 1 & 2

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#ChartstoDisplayAll').change(
              function () {
                  if ($('#ChartstoDisplayAll').is(':checked')) {
                      $(this).next().addClass("selected");
                      $('#buttons').addClass("buttonsshow").removeClass('buttonshide');
                      
                } else {
                      $('#buttons').addClass("buttonshide").removeClass('buttonsshow');
                      $(this).next().removeClass("selected");
                  }
              });
      });

Comment: @dinotom - sounds like what you are trying to do is something like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PugWc/4/) ???

Comment: Yes exactly...i figured it out with both your help and Nahian's. My script is posted at the end of my original question. I also have the script working now for the individual items in the checkboxlist